# java.lang.VeriryError encountered

Tags: android, runtime-error

Deat developers.

I have made an application but i encounter the following problem:

Occasionally (not always - some times) i get the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper
at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:103)
at development.nk.games.tanc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have looked after this problem and i read that i have to check all Libraries. I did that but the problem still is there.

The class "GameHelper" is a helper class that i use from google play services.
"MainActivity" is the main Activity my app runs. "MainActivity" extends "BaseGameActivity" which uses the "GameHelper" class.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Verify if the library you are using are the same at compile & runtime ? There might be version mismatch

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you be more specific? what do you mean by compile and runtime version mismatch ? how can these two be not the same?